# DotNetRdf Sparql propertypaths with cardinality issue?

Tags: rdf, sparql, dotnetrdf

I have a hierarchy of business activity , I want to filter companies on a specific activity so I mean to capture all companies that work in the specific activity or any of its descendants.

Activities are assigned through the my:hasActivity predicate and hierarchy is expressed with a my:isPartOf predicate (that is meant to be transitive)

So to filter the resultset I add a this pattern in my query :

```
?company my:asActivity/my:isPartOf* @base
```

I expect it to be equivalent to an induction pattern like :

```
      { ?company my:hasActivity @base }
UNION { ?company my:hasActivity ?s1 . ?s1 my:isPartOf @base }
...
UNION { ?company my:hasActivity ?s_n . ?s_n my:isPartOf ?s_(n-1) . [...] . ?s1 my:isPartOf @base }
```

but the results I get are inconsistent with this.

Am I wrong in my assumptions or is there a issue with this propertyPath pattern in DotNetRdf ?

As it is, it would seem that the sparql engine looses the constraint between the my:hasActivity triple object and the my:isPartOf subject...

Thanks in advance for your advice,
Max.

Comment: Can you post the entire SPARQL query, and possibly some sample data against which you expect the query to produce some results?  Then we can check whether the SPARQL is correctly formed or not, and if it is, whether it actually produces the expected results.  If the SPARQL is wrong, then the issue isn't DotNetRDF specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in dotNetRDF that has now been fixed and so should work again from the 1.0.1 release onwards.

#### Original Answer

It's a known bug in dotNetRDF - see [CORE-349](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/tracker/Issues/IssueDetail.aspx?id=349), I haven't actually done any debugging on this other than to confirm the bug exists so I have no idea when it will get fixed.

Comment: ok, thanks for the reply. I was not sure I had the right understanding. I'll try to make a fix in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks to @Max and another user was able to successfully debug and resolve the issue, fix is in default and will be in next releae